# Blur event not working for PrimeNG autocomplete in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeNG autocomplete in Angular 2 application and I am trying to call a method on blur event, but it does not call the method. Below is the code:

html:

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="empText" inputStyleClass="form-control" [minLength]="1" [suggestions]="empData"
    field="text" (completeMethod)="getEmployeeData($event)" 
    (blur)="onBlur($event.target.value)" (change)="onEmpDataChanged($event.target.value)"></p-autoComplete>
```

I have the following method in my component.ts:

```
    // Set touched on blur
    onBlur(e: any) {
        alert("control is blurred");
        this.onTouchedCallback();
    }
```

I tried with the change event and it works fine but the blur for autocomplete is not working. Any suggestions why the onBlur method is not called.

Answer (score 1):

For your information, this one is fixed in current version 4.0.0-RC.3

Answer (score -1):

Try with **onBlur** instead of **blur**

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="empText" inputStyleClass="form-control" [minLength]="1" [suggestions]="empData"
    field="text" (completeMethod)="getEmployeeData($event)" 
    (onBlur)="onBlur($event.target.value)" (change)="onEmpDataChanged($event.target.value)"></p-autoComplete>
```

Comment: The onBlur event does not work because there is no even emitter for "onBlur" in the p-autocomplete component in primeNG. I have created a github issue and waiting for it to be fixed.